# IPY widget Datetimepicker subtract date.today()

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, widget, ipywidgets

Hi I'm trying to get the number of days between the date selected with the widget and today's date but I get the following error:
*unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'datetime.date'*

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from datetime import date


last_connected = widgets.DatePicker(
    description='Pick a Date',
    disabled=False)


def days_between(last):
    return last_connected.value - date.today()
    #return abs((last - date.today()).days)

widgets.interactive(days_between,
                    last = last_connected)
```

Comment: i had to add `display(last_connected)` to get it to work...  ('vscode' interactive).

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question (use module that i have not seen before) and got my upvote.

I have just tried this in the interactive window of `vs code` and it works like this:

```py
# %% the first cell to run
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
from datetime import date


last_connected = widgets.DatePicker(
    description='Pick a Date',
    disabled=False)

display(last_connected)


# %% the second cell to run
def days_between(last):
    return last - date.today()

x = days_between(last_connected.value)
print(x)

print('done')
```

The result look like this:

[image]

You should note that the `# %%` separate the cells, so the widget cell has to be run first (to get the value). Before the second cell is run. Which i expect is consistent with jupyter.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would it be possible to make the date picked with ipywidgets automaticaly change x, the number of dates between both cells, without having to execute the second cell?

Comment: yes, it seem that the user can do all kinds of combinations...  the value stored goes into memory and is run at the next cell.